# Convert Table string to the actual table

Tags: lua

```
local t = "{{2173,1},{2160,5}}"
print(#t) -- 19?? wrong
```

How to convert to appear in numbers?

```
local t = {{2173,1},{2160,5}}
print(#t) -- 2 correct
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run the string through `load` or `loadstring` (depending on your Lua version), which will return the table you are looking for:

```
local t = "{{2173,1},{2160,5}}"
t = (loadstring or load)("return "..t)()
print(#t) -- 2
```

Comment: May be, `loadstring or load`?

Comment: worked too!! And certainly in a simpler way !! Nice!

Comment: On Lua 5.1 `(load or loadstring)` evaluates to `load`, and `load` expects a function as its argument.  `load("return")` will result in runtime error.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an ad hoc solution for the input you gave:

```
local s = "{{2173,1},{2160,5}}"
local t = {}
local n = 0
for a,b in s:gmatch("(%d+),(%d+)") do
        n = n + 1
        t[n] = {a,b}
end
for k,v in ipairs(t) do print(k,v[1],v[2]) end
```